# SQLite The database file is locked (database is locked)

Tags: java, sqlite

We have created a software using java which is connected with sqlite database.everything works good. But when we press on a buttom to open the database we got a message that database is locked.
`[SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)`

So we can not use it at all .. What is the reason of that error? How can we fix it too?

This code is for that button that we have problem with:

```
String id_patient = id.getText();

int idd, idd1 = 0;
idd = Integer.valueOf(first011.a55); //first011.a55 = id_patient

Connection connection22;
Statement statement22, stat, statement44, statement2;

connection22 = null;
try {
 connection22 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\workspace\\FAMRSOFTWARE\\dataessai.sqlite");
 statement2 = connection22.createStatement();
 statement2.setQueryTimeout(30);
 statement22 = connection22.createStatement();
 statement22.setQueryTimeout(30);
 stat = connection22.createStatement();
 stat.setQueryTimeout(30);

 statement44 = connection22.createStatement();
 statement44.setQueryTimeout(30);


 //This is to take and use id_demand from an other table in database

 ResultSet Resultat = statement22.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM demandes WHERE ID_patient =" + first011.a55);
 while (Resultat.next()) {
  String iddemande = Resultat.getString("ID_demande");
  idd1 = Integer.valueOf(iddemande);
 }


 int i = 0;
 int string;
 String idanalyse;
 while (i < tablee.getRowCount()) {
  if (!(tablee.getValueAt(i, 0) == null)) {

   statement22.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO datails (ID_demande, ID_analyse ) VALUES ('" + idd1 + "', '" + Integer.valueOf((String) tablee.getValueAt(i, 0)) + "')");
   i++;

  } else {
   break;
  }
 }


 i = 0;
 while (i < tablee.getRowCount()) {
  if (!(tablee.getValueAt(i, 0) == null)) {

   ResultSet Resultat2 = statement44.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM parametres WHERE ID_analyse =" + tablee.getValueAt(i, 0));
   while (Resultat2.next()) {
    stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fichetechnique (ID_patient, ID_parametre, ID_analyse ) VALUES ('" + id.getText() + "', '" + Resultat2.getString("ID_parametre") + "', '" + tablee.getValueAt(i, 0) + "')");

   }

   i++;
  } else break;
 }
 statement2.executeUpdate("UPDATE demandes SET total = '" + apayer.getText() + "',versement = '" + v.getText() + "' WHERE ID_patient = " + first011.a55);
 //statement2.executeUpdate("UPDATE demandes SET  versement = '"+v.getText()+"' WHERE ID_patient = "+first011.a55);

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Les Analyses de ce patient est enregistrer avec succès !! ");

} catch (SQLException e1) {

 System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
}


setVisible(false);
```

Comment: If you aren't going to use `try...with...resources` statement in order to close `connection`, it is not surprisingly that database can become locked

Comment: `What is the reason of that error?` There is a file pointer that the OS keeps exclusively locked for the resource (DB file), using a semaphore or mutex, preventing read access apparently. There are different lock states, and a common one is allow reading while DB is locked for writing, for example.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you please clarify what you mean by `when we press on a buttom to open the database we got a message that database is locked` I'm assuming you get the lock exception when you run a DB admin tool/editor while this other app is running? Or maybe you have a button within your app that loads the DB?